# Node JS Promises not working on local server

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I created "small" server that shoud use NodeJs and promises to copy and compres files of given type from given directory. It had to be separeted, each in promise - reading files and packing them. First I created just those promises to check if they would work, and they did:

```
function packFile(file){
    var fileName = path.basename(file);
    console.log('   (+) Add to the archive : ' + fileName + ' ['+file+']');
    archive.append(fs.createReadStream(file), { name:fileName });
}

Q.nfcall(recursive, pathGiven, filterGiven)         
.then(function(data) {                                  
    var chain = Q.when();   
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){   
    console.log(' > '+data[i]+' > adding to chain ...');
    chain = chain.then(packFile.bind(this, data[i]));
}

chain.then(function() {
    archive.finalize();
});
```

Ofc, i added, in front of previouslty presented code:

```
fs = require('fs');
archiver = require('archiver');
Q = require('q');
recursive = require('recursive-readdir');
path = require('path');
```

All those were isntalled and working fine. "archive" is also corrently initialized at the beggining.

Since all worked- it was time to get on with a server:

```
//Lets require/import the HTTP module
var http = require('http');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Function "handleRequest" is quite big, so to get just the gist of it i will place part where is shoud handle those promises:

```
switch(request.url) {
    case '/formhandler': 
        if (request.method == 'POST') {     
        // (...) Got my "Sour" (Path to source directory ) and "Mask"
        // Here i tried to place that promise chain, but server just skipped it and continued

        Q.nfcall(recursive, Sour, Mask)         
        .then(function(data) {                                  
            var chain = Q.when();   
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){   
                console.log(' > '+data[i]+' > adding to chain ...');
                chain = chain.then(packFile.bind(this, data[i]));
            }
            chain.then(function() {
                console.log("whole chain resolved");
                console.log('FINISHING');
                archive.finalize();
            });         
        });

        // (...) Finishing this request
        }
    break;
}
```

Nothing I do seems to work. As long as I use those promises (calling them like that or in some function). I have no idea why.

**EDIT 1**
What i mean by skipped - I placed 2 console.log before and after promises in that handler. I shoud see:

```
 LOG1
 TEXT_FROM_PROMISES //Something those promises send to console.log
 LOG2
```

But there was only:

```
 LOG1
 LOG2
```

And server was ready to get another request.

**EDIT 2**
Some suggested in comments to change packFile so it would return promise, so i did:

```
function packFile(file){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var fileName = path.basename(file);
        console.log('   (+) Adding to the archive : ' + fileName + ' ['+file+']');
        archive.append(fs.createReadStream(file), { name:fileName });           
    });
}
```

Rest of the code is unchanged. Result is - Now ONLY FIRST from this chain will be performed (if I call it "alone" in script, without server) and it still wont work on server.

**EDIT 3**

I changed 'packFile' again:

```
function packFile(file){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var fileName = path.basename(file);
        console.log('   (+) Adding to the archive : ' + fileName + ' ['+file+']');
        archive.append(fs.createReadStream(file), { name:fileName });   
        resolve("Success!");            
    });
}
```

Not whole chain will work - for no-server version, but still - nothing happen on server.

**EDIT 4**
I changed

```
    Q.nfcall(recursive, pathGiven, filterGiven)         
    .then(function(data) {                                  
        var chain = Q.when();   
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){   
            console.log(' > '+data[i]+' > adding to chain ...');
            chain = chain.then(packFile.bind(this, data[i]));
        }
        chain.then(function() {
            console.log("whole chain resolved");
            archive.finalize(); 
        });         
    }, function(reason) {
        console.log("ERROR:"+reason); // Error!
    });
```

and got some new error in console:

```
ERROR:TypeError: ignores.map is not a function
```

**EDIT 5**
Code I use for archive, just to make and open .zip to add files to with my 'packFile'

```
    archive = archiver.create('zip', {});
    var output = fs.createWriteStream('./output.zip');
    archive.pipe(output);
```

**EDIT 6**
Since there seems to be need for more code, tehre is function I call on my server whenever i recive proper request (-> check beggining of this post)

```
    function handleWithPromises(pathGiven, filterGiven){
        console.log('  > Promising ...');

        archive = archiver.create('zip', {});
        var output = fs.createWriteStream('./output.zip');
        archive.pipe(output);  

        function packFile(file){
            return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
                var fileName = path.basename(file);
                console.log('   (+) Adding to the archive : ' + fileName + ' ['+file+']');
                archive.append(fs.createReadStream(file), { name:fileName });   
                resolve("Success!");            
            });
        }

        Q.nfcall(recursive, pathGiven, filterGiven)         
        .then(function(data) {                                  
            var chain = Q.when();   
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){   
                console.log(' > '+data[i]+' > adding to chain ...');
                chain = chain.then(packFile.bind(this, data[i]));
            }
            chain.then(function() {
                console.log('FINISHING');
                archive.finalize();
            });         
        });
    }
```

and code that is placed at the very begging of script:

```
    fs = require('fs');
    archiver = require('archiver');
    Q = require('q');
    recursive = require('recursive-readdir');
    path = require('path');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "skipped it"? Won't the request just keep processing since everything else is async?

Comment: I'm new to this technology. It just seems to ignore it - like there was nothing - files didn't get copied and compressed, not even single line from console.logs appeared in cmd's window.

Comment: Your `packFile` function is not `return`ing anything. If it doesn't return a promise, there is no reason to build a chain with it.

Comment: But `packFile` dosent have return anything - it just compres single file. I dont realy know how i shoud correct this.

Comment: @Arker what Bergi is saying is, `packFile` must return a promise, only then, the chain might wait till the `packFile` operation finishes before moving on to next..

Comment: Yes, i got what he said - but i still dont know how i shoud change this code.

Comment: @Arker: Doesn't `archive.append` take a callback at least? Or if it is not asynchronous in itself, should it just be called in a normal loop, and the callback might be passed to `finalise`? Or is it asynchronous at all?

Comment: @Arker: Just seen your edit. Now `packFile` returns a promise, but a promise that is never resolved. It seemed you wanted to execute each `append` call only when the previous one had finished, so you'd need to get a promise for *that*. If there is no result, and no asynchrony, then you don't need promises at all.

Comment: At this point - i just want to resolve this issue, make it work and close this "project".

Comment: Well, tell us how `archive` is supposed to work, and we can tell you how to utilise promises.

Comment: As described in my question - I have a server. When i get request (req. containt dirrectory's path and mask) I have to read all files (use mask to check if fits) from that directory and it's sub-dirrectories, after that (i shoud be next promise) I have to take all those selected and compreset to single .zip/.rar. That's all.

Comment: You seem to use some `archiver = require('archiver');` library. Did you read its API docs? Btw, the latest error message you posted in the edit does not come from any of the code you've shown to us.

Comment: Still is seems very strange to me. I dont realy get it WHY my code works, without even that error when i just use it solo, but with server it all goes to hell. I realy need some serious help with correcting this....

Answer (score 1):

Go back to **Edit 1** where you expected to see

```
LOG1
TEXT_FROM_PROMISES //Something those promises send to console.log
LOG2
```

but got

```
LOG1
LOG2
```

An explanation is that A+ compliant promises interface with the event loop scheduler to execute functions supplied with `then` in their own thread, after the thread that called `then` executes to completion.

**Chained promises execute asynchronously to the code that defines them.**

On a very simplistic level, you will need to postpone ending the request until all files have been packed by making sure `response` is in function scope of the last anonymous function and ending the response there:

```
       chain.then(function() {
            console.log('FINISHING');
            archive.finalize();
            response.write(...)   // are you sending the archive back?
            response.end();     // now end the request
        });
```